# How to disable syntax check in c header file

Tags: c++, lua

I'm embedding Lua code in cplusplus; it's ok to write like

```cpp
char const *lua_scripts = R"rawstring(

-- lua code

)rawstring";
```

But the Lua code inside the string doesn't have syntax highlight, so I split it into 3 files:
The first file is called `head.txt`

```cpp
char const *lua_scripts = R"rawstring(
```

The second file is called `body.lua`

```lua
 -- lua code
```

The third file is called `tail.txt`

```cpp
)rawstring";
```

Then the original cpp file changed to

```cpp
#include "head.txt"
#include "body.lua"
#include "tail.txt"
```

But when I compile, syntax error reported, because the compiler checked the file before inclusion. So how can I disable compiler checking syntax?

Comment: Pretty sure you can't end a file with an open quoted string.  Your best option might be to treat any embedded code as generated, even if the generation is effectively doing `cat head.txt body.lua tail.txt >some_header.h`.

Comment: `char const lua_scripts` describes a single character, not a string.

Comment: Consider writing a simple pre-build step that builds your string resources from their original source files.  By doing that, you can easily update your program later to obfuscate the strings if you want them "hidden" in the executable (using a simple chain of XOR, or even a more elaborate obfuscation or encryption scheme). It also avoids the hassle (and ultimately futile effort) of using precompiler hacks.

Comment: Pretty close to an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You are asking for help with your proposed solution before understanding the problem you are trying to solve. Did you think about why you needed to split into *three* files? If you knew why simply moving just the Lua code to `body.lua` does not work, you would know why your current 3-file approach is doomed to failure. (Speaking of which, would you be interested in asking why moving just the Lua code to `body.lua` does not work? Or would you rather ask for a work-around?)

Comment: @paddy Sorry, it's a typo. It's `char const *lua_scripts`

Comment: I probably could have phrased that better. I meant that the question you are asking is not going to help you. I see two productive ways to alter your question: either ask why your approach fails, or ask for a workaround for your original problem (not the three-include approach). Which of these is of more interest to you?

Comment: @JaMiT My original problem is the Lua code inside the string doesn't have a syntax highlight. I thought the c preprocessor only merge files, the syntax checking is on the compile phase.

Comment: @Divlaker *"I thought the c preprocessor only merge files"* -- that is a commonly-used simplification that works in most cases. Until you try to get too fancy. There are actually [nine phases of translation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases); the preprocessor is phase 4. The simplification assumes that phases 1-3 are not relevant.

Comment: @JaMiT but the txt files and lua file are not source files

Comment: @Divlaker *"but the txt files and lua file are not source files"* -- right, they are used as header files, rather than as source files. (The preprocessor does not care about file extensions, nor about what you believe the file type is.) So, would it be fair to conclude that you would like to focus this question on why your attempt failed?

Answer (score 2):

In C++, programs are parsed after preprocessing. But dividing the input into lexemes is done before preprocessing. The input to the preprocessor is a stream of tokens, not a stream of characters.

So a token cannot span two input files. And a string literal is a single token.

You also may not split preprocessor directives over two files, so `#endif`, `#else`, etc. must all be in the same file as the `#if` or `#ifdef`, and the last line in a file cannot end with a backslash line-splice.

You could easily write your own little merging program which builds a C++ file from the C++ and Lua source files. You could even write it in Lua, its not that complicated. Or you could do it with the M4 macro processor, which is most likely already installed in your compilation environment.

Answer (score 0):

There are [nine phases of translation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases) that occur when C++ code is compiled. Phase 3 is when string literals are identified. Phase 4 is the preprocessor. By the time the compiler gets to `#include` your files, all the string literals in your original source file have been found and marked as such. There will not be another pass of your source file looking for more literals after the preprocessor is done.

When the preprocessor brings in a file, that file goes through the first four phases of translation before being inserted into your original source file. This is slightly different than the common, simplified perception of a header file being directly copied into a source file. Rather than a character-by-character copy, the header is copied token-by-token, where "token" means "preprocessing token", which includes such things as identifiers, operators, and literals.

In practice, the simplified view is adequate until you try to have language elements cross file boundaries. In particular, neither comments nor string literals can start in one file and extend into another. (There are other examples, but it's a bit more contrived to bring them into play.) You tried to have a string literal begin in one file, extend into a second, and end in a third. This does not work.

When the preprocessor brings in `head.txt`, the first three phases analyze it as five preprocessor tokens followed by a non-terminated raw string literal.  This is what gets copied into your source file. Note that the non-terminated literal remains a non-terminated literal; it does not become a literal looking for an end.

When `body.lua` is brought in, it is treated just like any other header file. The preprocessor is not concerned about extensions. The file is brought in and subject to the phases of translation just like any other `#include`. Phase 3 will identify, using C++ syntax rules, string literals that begin in `body.lua`, but no part of `body.lua` will become part of a string literal that begins outside `body.lua`. Phase 3, including the identification of string literals, happens on this file in isolation.

Your approach has failed.

---

> So how can I disable compiler checking syntax?

You cannot disable compiler syntax checking. That's like asking how can you have a person read a book without picking out letters and words. You've asked the compiler to process your code, and the first step of that is making sure the code is understandable, i.e. has valid syntax. It's questions like this that remind us that [XY problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) are as prevalent as ever.

Fortunately, though, you did mention your real problem: "doesn't have syntax highlight". Unfortunately, you did not provide enough information about your real problem, such as what program is providing the syntax highlighting. I subjected the following to two different syntax highlighters; one highlighted the Lua code as Lua code, and the other did not.

```lua
R"rawstring(
 -- lua code 
)rawstring"
```

If you are willing to ignore the highlighting on the first and last lines, and if your editor successfully applies the desired syntax highlighting, you could make this your `body.lua` file. Then the following C++ code should work.

```cpp
char const *lua_scripts =
#include "body.lua"
;
```

Statements are not identified until phase seven – well after the preprocessor – so you *can* split statements across files.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the unix `xxd` utility in a pre-build step to preprocess your `body.lua` file as follows:

```bash
xxd -i body.lua body.xxd
```

Then in your c++ code:

```cpp
#include "body.xxd"
const std::string lua_scripts(reinterpret_cast<char *>(body), body_len);
```